# Do I have to use sucrose to induce a lac promoter?

Tags: bacteriology, lab-techniques, protein-expression

I'd like to optimize the expression of a F<sub>ab</sub> fragment in *Escherichia coli*.
For induction of the *lac* promoter on the pAK400 vector I use IPTG and sucrose. Do I optimize the expression in case I would just add IPTG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can induce the lac operon by two things: Lactose (or more precisely Allolactose a metabolite of it) and lactose analogons which are not metabolized by the bacteria.

Lactose induces the expression and is metabolized while [IPTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_%CE%B2-D-1-thiogalactopyranoside) is not a target of the $\beta$-Galactosidase and will give you a strong and permanent induction. Sucrose will not have any effect on the promoter.